# Unwanted delayed UPDATE through operating system scheduling?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, locking

We are running into a very strange problem with disjunct concurrent PHP processes accessing the same table (using table locks).

There is no replication involved, we're working on a monolith with the mysqli-interface of PHP 5.6.40 (I know, upgrading is due, we're working on it).

Let's say the initial value of a field namend "value" in xyz is 0;

PHP-Process 1: Modifies the table

```
LOCK TABLE xyz WRITE;
UPDATE xyz SET value = 1;
UNLOCK TABLE xyz;
```

PHP-Process 2: Depends on a value in that table (e.g. a check for access rights)

```
SELECT value from xyz;
```

Now, if we manage to make Process 2 halt and wait for the lock to be released, on a local dev-Environment (XAMPP, MariaDB 10.1.x), everything is fine, it will get the value 1;

BUT, on our production server (DebianLinux, MySQL 5.6.x) there is a seemingly necessary wait period for the value to materialize in query results.

- An immediate SELECT statement delivers 0
- sleep(1) then SELECT delivers 1

We always assumend that a) LOCK / UNLOCK will Flush Tables or b) A manual FLUSH TABLES xyz WITH READ LOCK will also flush caches, enforcing writing to the disc and generally will ensure that every following query of every other process will yield the expected result.

What we tried so far:

- FLUSH TABLES as mentioned - no result
- Explicitly acquire a LOCK before executing the SELECT statement - no result
- Just wait some time - yielded the result we are looking for, but this is a dirty, unreliable solution.

What do you guys think? What might be the cause? I was thinking of: The query cache not updating in time, paging of the underlying OS not writing stuff back to the disk in time / not validating the memory page of the table data.

Is there any way you know to definitely assure consecutive consistentcy of the data?

Comment: So it turns out that this behaviour does NOT happen in the MyISAM engine. We turned the problematic table back to MyISAM as a valid solution would be a complex Locking-mechanism that's not reliant to mySQL / MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

There are different transaction isolation modes by default in the different MariadB versions.

You have set up the same mode if you expect the same result. It also seems weird to test it on different MySQL versions.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-transactions-and-isolation-levels-for-sql-server-users/

Your second process do start of transaction may be far before the commit actually issued.
If you do not want dig in transaction isolation just try do rollback before select(but correct solution is determine what exactly isolation your app require).

```
Rollback; -- may give error, but it is okay.
SELECT value from xyz;
```

Comment: The testing on different versions is because a server upgrade can only be done after a lot of legacy code changes - we unfortunately have to live with this now, we are locally developing on xampp-Windows-Environments.

The problem runs on MySQL, which should just LOCK everything as desired - this is not the problem, the locks prevent a real concurrent execution. The problem is that AFTER the UPDATE (and Lock release), the other process sees OLD data in the table. The MariaDB-Doc does not help this - but thank you anyway :)

Comment: Have you tried add rollback or change isolation level per-transaction?

Comment: It's a myISAM table and I know this is not ok. Will discuss changing to INNODB and changing the isolation Level - thank you! I'll report back on this ticket to comment if it worked.

Comment: On my isam there are only table level locks. So it is not applicable. But changing to innodb is the nice idea anyway(except if you are running on really low-memory machines like 128Mb).

Comment: Yeah the thing is - We sometimes need full table locks - e.G. nobody shall be able to insert a cashbox booking while another thread is in the process of closing the cash register - preventing anyone from adding further bookings for today. The specific problem here is that obviously data was not fully commited when releasing the lock...

Comment: Use explict locking for that.

Comment: Oh wow I just found out that we have an innodb-table where this problem occurs - so that was my fault. Will look into that.